# dd-trace-java: `Could not notify the extension as the lambda span is null or no sampling priority has been found`

Tags: aws-lambda, datadog

I have upgraded Datadog lambda layer for my Kotlin lambda function. The lambda is running on java17, and the layer version is `dd-trace-java` 11 and `Datadog-Extension` 47, just same as guided here : https://docs.datadoghq.com/serverless/guide/upgrade_java_instrumentation/?lang_pref=en

I've checked the lambda function itself is running correctly, but no trace is sent to Datadog. dd-trace raises an error of

```
[main] ERROR datadog.trace.lambda.LambdaHandler - Could not notify the extension as the lambda span is null or no sampling priority has been found
```

I think some kind of lambda span exists since the function works, but is there any cases which raises this error?